# NDK error: "can't resolve `.data.rel.ro.local'"

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-ndk

Android/NDK project, worked with NDK versions all the way up to r8c. Under 8d and 8e, I get a compilation error message on the armeabi-v7a build:

```
Compile++ thumb  : myproject <= MyFile.cpp
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccFXOc2F.s: Assembler messages:
C:\cygwin\tmp\ccFXOc2F.s:1935: Error: can't resolve `.data.rel.ro.local' {.data.rel.ro.local section} - `.LPIC44' {*UND* section}
```

The armeabi, MIPS, and x86 builds for the same project are successful.

It's reliably popping up on the same file. The file is nothing special - vanilla C++, it compiles and works on numerous other platforms (iOS, Windows, NDK r8c to name some). No STL. It does define a healthy amount of string constants though (AKA initialized read/only data). What could be going on?

Already tried a full rebuild, even deleted the `obj` folder altogether.

The C++ flags are:

```
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -fshort-wchar -fsigned-char -Wno-psabi
```

I know NDK comes with several versions of GCC; might a toolchain change help? How exactly?

Comment: Were you able to check what was at line 1935 of temporary assembly file?

Comment: No; the assembly would disappear from the temp folder by the time *make* terminated. I used, instead, a tried and true technique of commenting out the body of every function in a file, then adding code back little by little until the error reappeared. This approach converges on the faulty line in O(log N) time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely looks like a compiler bug to me. It's related to indexed access to a large chunk of static const data. When I've slightly reformulated a perfectly innocent statement, the error message went away.

Used to be:

```
//In global scope
static const LPCWSTR Comments[] = {L"A lot of strings here", L"String 2", L"String 3" /* and many more */ }:

void SomeMethod()
{
    DoSomething(Comments[i]); //That was the offending line - commenting it out would get rid the error
}
```

Replaced with:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    static LPCWSTR pComments = 0;
    if(!pComments)
        pComments = Comments;

    DoSomething(pComments[i]); //Now it works.
}
```

Ooky, spooky stuff.